# Is it can use single yield put apply all data

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I try update redux from value as below according to my API call response. I want use one yield in redux saga instead of below all yield.

```
yield put(change('employeeCostForm', 'A1', <new A1 value>));
yield put(change('employeeCostForm', 'A2', <new A2 value>));
yield put(change('employeeCostForm', 'A3', <new A3 value>));
...
...
yield put(change('employeeCostForm', 'An', <new An value>));
```

Please give me advice use these most best way. what Is best practice?

Comment: See https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/459#issuecomment-433910933

Comment: I dont't use **SagaEffects**. which scenario is it use?

Comment: `SagaEffects` is just an alias for all saga effects like `import * as SagaEffects from 'redux-saga/effects'`. If you're importing individual effects you can do `import {all, put} from 'redux-saga/effects';` for example. Here is the documentation for the `all` effect: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects